# how to store checked check boxes in local storage

Tags: reactjs

I have some checked check-boxes. After checking a checkbox, that checked box need to be save in local storage. Can any one tell me about that?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import FormGroup from '@material-ui/core/FormGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import { List, ListItem } from '@material-ui/core';

class CheckboxComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <form action="/action_page.php">
          <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
          <label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
          <label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat">
          <label for="vehicle3"> I have a boat</label><br><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default CheckboxComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example of setting and removing items directly to / from `localStorage` and `this.state` on each checkbox click. Also on mount the state will be updated from `localStorage`.

```
class CheckboxComponent extends Component {

    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      items: {}
    }
  }

  handleCheckboxClick = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    const item = localStorage.getItem(name);
    if (item) {
      console.log(`Remove item name: ${name}, value: ${value}`);
      localStorage.removeItem(name);
      this.setState(state => delete state.items[name])
    } else {
      console.log(`Set item name: ${name}, value: ${value}`);
      localStorage.setItem(name, value);
      this.setState(state => state.items[name] = value);
    }
  }

  getLocalStorageItems = () => {
    const storageKeys = Object.keys(localStorage);
    let obj = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < storageKeys.length; i++) {
      obj[ storageKeys[i] ] = localStorage.getItem(storageKeys[i]);
    }
    this.setState({ items: obj });
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getLocalStorageItems();
  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return (
      <form action="/action_page.php">
        <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike" checked={items["vehicle1"] !== undefined} onChange={event => this.handleCheckboxClick(event)} />
        <label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Car" checked={items["vehicle2"] !== undefined} onChange={event => this.handleCheckboxClick(event)} />
        <label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat" checked={items["vehicle3"] !== undefined} onChange={event => this.handleCheckboxClick(event)} />
        <label for="vehicle3"> I have a boat</label><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

If you want to read more about LocalStorage you can refer to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp) for a quick explanation, or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for a more in depth explanation.
*Note that data set on `localStorage` persists between browser sessions until it is removed.*

Note that this is probably not the most efficient way to do this, but it should get you started. Also you can convert this to a [functional component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) using [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), but I kept to the class component API to keep things easier to understand.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: thanks very much Opearl..its working....but i just want like...if i checked the check box..it should be constant with checked and save in local storage....untill i remove checked from the checkbox..

Comment: no Opearl...its not working as i expected..after checked the checkbox...when i  went another component..and came back ...check box was unchecked...it should be checked....till refresh the page

Comment: Oh ok... so please explain exactly what you want. If you want the checkbox state to persist until refresh you can use component local state. But `localStorage` persists even after page refresh. So which one do you want? And if you want both how do you want to sync them?

Comment: Hey @ManuPanduu I updated the code to suit your needs. I would still recommend putting some thought to the different ways you can sync between `localStorage` and `this.state`.

Comment: thanks very much for your answer....i let you know about that....after completing my task...of mine...